# Is it possible to use CodePipeline to Deploy an artifact to an s3 bucket in a different AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline

A couple of weeks ago, AWS added the feature to use CodePipeline to deploy to S3. See the announcement here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-deploying-to-amazon-s3/

One of the required arguments to this new deployment type is a bucket name (not a bucket arn). Upon passing a bucket name in a different AWS account into the configuration box, the configuration fails to populate.

Additionally, if I create a pipeline with terraform, create an S3 deployment action, specify a role that grants access to the s3 bucket in a different AWS account, and specify the bucket name in question, the pipeline is created, but the configuration for the bucket name in the deploy step ends up empty.

Is there a way to use this feature to deploy to a s3 bucket in a different AWS account? This seems like an obvious use case which should be supported and yet I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the console? Does the pipeline run like you're expect and you're describing a display problem? Can you add more detail about the permissions setup?

Comment: I tried it programmatically first using terraform. I then tried it in the console. Permission setup is as follows: Account A has codepipeline / code pipeline role. Account B has s3 bucket and s3 permissions role, assumable by Account A codepipeline role. Account A tries to assume s3 permissions role and execute deploy action. But deploy action is missing configuration. Because it is impossible to add configuration to a deploy to S3 action in Account A targeting a bucket in Account B.

Comment: Is the S3 deploy action configured with the Account B role? I'm wondering if the role in Account B has permission to access the S3 bucket used for pipeline artifacts (distinct from the S3 bucket you're deploying to)? The role used by the S3 deploy action needs access to both the source (pipeline artifacts) and destination (where you're publishing to).